# start LyX on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to use LyX (a document processor) on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10.
I installed LyX with apt-get.

```
$ sudo apt-get install lyx
```

It succeeded.
Then I tried to start LyX with

```
$ lyx
```

but it failed.

```
lyx: cannot connect to X server
```

How can I fix this problem?